# Using ConfigurationBuilder with a json file to add null to list

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, configuration

I am trying to put a list of enums into appsettings.json that will be iterated through at one point in the code. The problem is that if I put a null value into the list in the json file, it does not populate a null value into the list when the Settings are loaded from the file.

minimum code example:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().
            AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json");

        var config = builder.Build();
        
        var test = config.GetRequiredSection("Settings").Get<Settings>();
        test.EnumList.Add(null);
    }
}

class Settings
{
    public enum EnumValues
    {
        Value1,
        Value2
    }
    public List<EnumValues?> EnumList { get; set; }
}
```

json file:

```
{
    "Settings": {
        "EnumList" :  [null, "Value1"]
    }
}
```

The test.EnumList.Add(null) will predictably and correctly add a null to the list, however, there will be no null in the list before that line, despite being in the json file. I would like to actually be able to put a null in the json file and have it show up in list.

How can I do this? I've hunted for a bit and I've come up with nothing.

Comment: Is there a way that you are using `JsonOptions` in your `startup` class? Are you using Newtonsoft?

Comment: Use "null" instead of null

Comment: Unfortunately, putting quotes around it does not work. I'm able to set other properties, not in lists, to null using just null.

Comment: Should have been more clear, Pablo, that I am using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrieving that `EnumList` as a list of strings, shows that that `null`  value is present, but has been stored as an empty string.

```
var strings = config.GetRequiredSection("Settings:EnumList").Get<List<string>>();
```

[image]

It looks like that `null` value gets lost when making that `Get<Settings>()` call.

The source code of the `ConfigurationBinder` at [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/src/ConfigurationBinder.cs#L671)
shows that an empty `string` or `null` value gets skipped for a generic nullable type - here `List<Settings.EnumValues?>`.

```
if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return TryConvertValue(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type)!, value, path, out result, out error);
}
```

---

To get arround that, declare that `EnumList` property as an `EnumValues?[]` array.

```
public class Settings
{
    public enum EnumValues
    {
        Value1,
        Value2
    }

    public EnumValues?[] EnumList { get; set; }
}
```

Now the parsed `Settings` will contain that `null` value - see image.

```
var test = config.GetRequiredSection("Settings").Get<Settings>();
```

[image]

---

With this array in place, you'll have to find an other way to add an item to it, e.g. something like below.

```
test.EnumList = test.EnumList
    .Concat(new Settings.EnumValues?[] 
    { 
        null // Or other value
    }).ToArray();
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you so much. This is a static value that is set only at start up, I actually encapsulate it so it can't be changed, so adding things to it is not necessary. I only did that to test that I could actually add a null to the list.